# How to store data on network or web in android?

Tags: networking, web, datastore

I am very new and going to develop simple application, where user share own information to all who register particular groups and network.how to stored that data on network, who view all information own or every members all information from the different point of location(different places) via the network or web.

So, Please give me details of idea behind the how to store my data on network or web? where every member easily access that data?

I have already done by try search on Internet but could get much more ideas behind the data store on web?

Answer (score 0):

It would be preferable to store the data over the network on databases and make other users grant access to these databases to access information.

It is very easy to store data in a remote database from android and retrieve as can be understood from the tutorial [here](http://fahmirahman.wordpress.com/2011/04/21/connection-between-php-server-and-android-client-using-http-and-json/).